# Bootup activity on SPI0, even when not enabled

Tags: boot, spi

RPi 3B+
uname -a
Linux GWf231a6 4.14.79-v7+ #1159 SMP Sun Nov 4 17:50:20 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
/boot/config.txt:
 #dtparam=spi=on

I'm getting weird waveforms on my SPI bus at boot even when SPI is disabled.
Pins in logic analyzer diagram (all default locations for SPI+CE0):
MOSI = BCM10
MISO = BCM9
CLK = BCM11
CS = BCM8

[image]

Does anyone have a clue what can be causing this? I need to use SPI and these pulses cause the SPI connection to behave irrationally.

Many thanks!
Knut

Comment: You're logic doesn't make sense... If

Comment: @Dirk I couldn't agree more, but that's what I get. I have checked on several RPi 3B+ with same result. The clock signal is for 56 bytes at 1 MHz, but as you can see it's not valid SPI. Something in the kernel or BCM chip must use the SPI pins for some other purpose during bootup.

Comment: Do you get the same result with standard Raspbian?

Comment: You're right, Knut, that's weird. SPI master is giving out clocks with 1111111... as data, then drinking beer, after that pulling down clock - and a slave THAT'S NOT SELECTED gives an answer. That doesn't make sense. On the other hand, no chip is selected: CS is high. So, what's the prob?

Comment: You can't see it in the resolution I posted, but sometimes during boot (not every time) I get a short zero pulse on CS. I just ran it and got a CS active of 5.9 ms, but I've seen shorter as well. I can recall down to 60 usec once. Just to be clear, I have nothing connected to the 40 pin header more than the analyzer when I measure. I'm booting with no user software running. I guess I will have to start disabling stuff one by one and see if I can catch the culprit. Ideas welcome!

Comment: I'm running Stretch lite now, previously tested with Raspbian Jessie, same result. That was on a 3B, now I have 3B+.